# Finding words that contain all but one letter in string

Tags: python, regex, string

First off, this is a homework assignment (due tomorrow, fun fact).  The goal for this assignment is to take a string the the user inputs, and then search through a dictionary file given to us and print out any word that has all but one of those letters.
The code I have so far is below. I attempted to use regular expressions, but it seems like that only works for patterns, and I do not want it to only find matching patterns, the letters can be anywhere in the word.
Another important note. I'm not allowed to use lists on this assignment, which is where I think I'm running into the most trouble. Along with that the length of the string will vary each time.

```
import re
dictionary = open('dictionary.txt','r')

def all_but_one_letter():
    user_string = input("Please enter a string of characters: ")
    print(user_string)
    line = 'begin'
    while line != "":
        line = dictionary.readline()
        line = line.rstrip()
        if re.findall(user_string, line) == 1:
            print(line)

all_but_one_letter()             

dictionary.close()
```

I also have to print a statement saying if nothing matches the criteria, but right now I'm more concerned with getting this working first. Any help, or hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "that has all but one of those letters". Any examples of input, dict and what should happen with this input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
s1 = "foobar"
s2 = "fooba"
st1 = set(s1)


print(len(st1.intersection(s2)) == len(st1) - 1)
True
```

You should use with to open your files and you can just iterate over the file object:

```
def all_but_one_letter():
    with open('dictionary.txt','r') as dictionary:
        user_string = input("Please enter a string of characters: ")
        for line in dictionary:
            words = line.rstrip().split() # split into individual words
            for word in words:
                st1 = set(user_string)
                if len(st1.intersection(word)) == len(st1) - 1:
                    print(word)
```

intersection will find common letters, if the intersection is equal to the length of set of s1 then all but one letters are equal

```
In [1]: s1 = "foobar" 
In [2]: s2 = "fooba"
In [3]: st1 = set(s1)    
In [4]: len(st1.intersection(s2)) == len(st1) - 1
Out[4]: True    
In [5]: s1 = "fooba"    
In [6]: s2 = "fooba"    
In [7]: st1 = set(s1)    
In [8]: len(st1.intersection(s2)) == len(st1) - 1
Out[8]: False
```

Comment: [I've slightly modified your answer, to fix unrelated to the main question issues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26514831/4279).

Answer (score 1):

This assumes there are no duplicate letters, i.e. one or the other strings contains two "a"s for example.  If there are letters that occur more than once you will have to find a way to delete each letter as it is found (since you can't use lists, copy letters not found to a new string).  Also, `dictionary.readline()` will go through the file once and position the pointer at the end of the file, so a subsequent `readline` the next time the program goes through the while loop will produce nothing since there is nothing to read from the end of a file.  You have to use `readlines()` or some other means to get the data into a list so you can iterate over it many times.  This code has not been tested so typos, etc. are up to you to fix.

```
def all_but_one_letter(dictionary):
    user_string = input("Please enter a string of characters: ")
    user_string=user_string.lower()
    print(user_string)
    found=0
    for line in dictionary:
        line = line.rstrip().lower()
        print(line) 
        if line in user_string:
            found += 1
        else:
            print("Not Found")

    if found == len(user_string)-1
        print("Success")
    else:
        print("Failure")

dictionary = open('dictionary.txt','r').readlines()
all_but_one_letter(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a list, you're restricted to checking each word in the dictionary file, one at a time. So let's write a function to do that:

```
def checkWord(word, letters):
    answer = 0
    for letter in letters:
        if letter in word:
            answer += 1
    if answer == len(letters)-1:  # `word` contains all but one letter
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now that we have that component, let's write a function to take input from the user and from that dictionary file:

```
def main(infilepath):
    letters = input("Enter a string of letters: ")
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            word = line.strip()
            if checkWord(word, letters):
                print(word, "has all but one letter in", letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

To print words from `dictionary.txt` that have all but one letter from a given user string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def all_but_one_letter(word, letters):
    """Whether *word* contains all but one letter from *letters*."""
    return len(letters.intersection(word)) == (len(letters) - 1)

letters = frozenset(input("Please enter a string of characters: "))
with open('dictionary.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            if all_but_one_letter(word, letters):
                print(word)
```

The implementation of `all_but_one_letter(word, letters)` is [suggested by @Padraic Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26513606/4279). I've modified his answer to fix unrelated to the main question small issues in the code.